# Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini

Tags: opencart, input

Проблема заключается в том,что на чистый Opencart 2.3.0.2 установил шаблон от Magentech ShoppyStore,поставил галочки на права администратора,всё было нормально. После чего установил Vqmod и сверху поставил multimerch marketplace 8.9,активировал модуль и сразу вылезли такие ошибки:

> **Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0**
>
> **Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\shoppyfast\system\library\session.php on line 30**
>
> **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\shoppyfast\system\library\session.php on line 50**
>
> **Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in C:\OpenServer\domains\shoppyfast\system\library\response.php on line 12**

И слетели права администратора.. На других шаблонах Magentech всё встаёт корректно.Скажите пожалуйста,как исправить эти ошибки....

Comment: Интересно, для чего может понадобиться слать на сервер более 1000 переменных? http://php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Comment: @Visman Вы просто с OpenCart мало общались. Бывает и 10 000 лимита не хватает.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день,

Во-первых, настоятельно рекомендую использовать самую последнюю версию Мультимерча (8.14.2). Версия 8.9 была выпущена более полугода назад, [многое исправили с тех пор](https://multimerch.com/resources/changelog/).

Во-вторых, даже в версии 8.9 Мультимерч не отправляет такого количества переменных при установке - пишите на support@multimerch.com, присылайте информацию из раздела Admin > MultiMerch > System > Debug - разберемся.

В-третьих, шаблоны от Magentech регулярно вызывают проблемы у наших пользователей, несмотря на их заявления о полной совместимости с Мультимерчем. Я бы рекомендовал использовать [один из поддерживаемых нами шаблонов](https://multimerch.com/opencart-themes/), для которых мы сами разрабатываем и содержим наборы совместимости.

Comment: А скажи те пожалуйста,вот этот модуль (https://en.e-abi.ee/opencart/payment/maksekeskus-ee-estonian-payment-methods-for-opencart-billing-api.html ) совместим с Multimecrh ??

Comment: @user290699 Да, Мультимерч поддерживает все стандартные Опенкартовские платежные модули для приема платежей от покупателей. Если планируется использовать его для выплат продавцам - нужно будет доработать.

Тут чуть больше про работу Мультимерча с платежами: https://multimerch.com/resources/guides/concepts/payments/

Comment: @user290699 С мультимагазинами тоже работает, хотя официально мы их не поддерживаем (изначально мультимагазины - не очень хорошо продуманная система).

Answer (score 0):

В шаблоне shoppystore для OC 3.0 присутствует модуль multi vender marketplace... а он будет работать с модулем оплаты о котором я спрашивал выше ?https://en.e-abi.ee/opencart/payment/maksekeskus-ee-estonian-payment-methods-for-opencart-billing-api.html .. и как реализованы выплаты продавцам??

Comment: "о котором я спрашивал выше" - о каком вы спрашивали выше? Это же ваше первое сообщение.